# Why do I get an exception here? Am I not casting properly?

Tags: c#, file, serialization, io

When I run this:

```
public List<Animal> LoadFromFile()
    {
        // DECLARING ITEMS FOR FILE MANIPULATION
        fs = new FileStream(FileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
        bf = new BinaryFormatter();
        List<Animal> tempList = new List<Animal>();

        // DE-SERIALIZING

        while (fs.Position < fs.Length)
        {
            Animal p = (Animal)bf.Deserialize(fs);
            tempList.Add(p);
        }

            return tempList;
    }
```

I get an exception of type System.InvalidCastException, saying:

Unable to cast object of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[AnimalShelterManager.Animal]' to type 'AnimalShelterManager.Animal'.

What does it mean? What is between the brackets is actually the type I want it to cast to when deserializing. The class containing the list and the Animal class, as well as those who inherit from it **are** all `[Serializable]`.

Comment: Could you change it to `var p = (List<Animal>)bf.Deserialize(fs);`, and comment out `tempList.Add(p);` just to see it works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error:

> Unable to cast object of type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[AnimalShelterManager.Animal]' to
>   type 'AnimalShelterManager.Animal'.

Says it all. you are casting a list of `Animal` into `Animal`, your deserialization is returning a list of items which probably has one element of `Animal`. debug your code and ensure this and use `FirstOrDefault()` to get the first element before casting.